# Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ an open set and $f$ a holomorphic function in $U-\{z_0\}, z_0\in U$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that $\int_{\partial R}f(z)dz=0$, where $R$ is any rectangle in $U$.

I tried to use Goursat's Theorem, but I can't conclude cause $f$ is not holomorphic in $z_0$. We have as hypotheses

- f is holomorphic in $U-\{z_0\}$
- $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=0$

Any hint?

Comment: The second condition should probably be $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=0$, and that implies that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=z_0$ (Riemann's theorem on removable singularities).

Comment: Yes, is that. Hmm, i read here about this theorem and i think its work. Thanks, help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ is bounded in $U$ by the second condition. Say $|f| < M. $Split the rectangle R into many rectangles whose $R_0, R_1, R_2 \dots$ etc. Let $R_0$ be the rectangle containing $z_0$. While splitting $R$ we can choose to make $R_0$ as small as possible.

Note that $\int_R f = \sum_i \int_{R_i} f$. However the integrals all vanish except for $i>0$ as $f$ is holomorphic in $R_1, R_2$ etc. Also, $\left |\int_{R_0}f \right|$ can be bounded by arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ through the ML inequality. So, we can see that $\int_R f = 0$